# Getting confused trying to bind IsChecked property of MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, menuitem

After looking around on StackOverflow and other websites, I can see that people have a lot of problems with binding properties and commands to `MenuItems` and `ContextMenus` because `ContextMenu` is not part of the WPF visual tree. Anyway, I've tried a few different solutions and am not having any luck.

I have a `MenuItem` that is part of a `ContextMenu`. The `ContextMenu` is part of a window that is bound to a ViewModel in its code behind like so:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get { return DataContext as MainWindowViewModel; } } 

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //There is a property in the App.xaml.cs file that refers to MainWindowViewModel
        DataContext = App.MainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

The property that I am trying to bind to in `MainWindowViewModel`:

```
private bool _askBeforeDownloading_Checked = true;

public bool AskBeforeDownloading_Checked
{
    get { return _askBeforeDownloading_Checked; }
    set
    {
        _askBeforeDownloading_Checked = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => AskBeforeDownloading_Checked);
    }
}
```

My current attempt in XAML:

```
<Button Name="Button_1" >
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
            <MenuItem >
                <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.AskBeforeDownloading_Checked}" />
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

I came up with my current XAML based on the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904635/wpf-menuitem-ischecked-binding-not-working), along with [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162784/WPF-ContextMenu-Strikes-Again-DataContext-Not-Upda). What am I missing? I'm not getting any output errors, but the `MenuItem` is not getting checked. Is there something that I am not doing with `PlacementTarget`?

**Update:** I thought it would be important to note that my `ContextMenu` is a child control of a `Button`. I've added it to my XAML.

**Update 2:** After using Snoop on my application I found that my `Button` was automatically inheriting from `MainWindowViewModel` as it should. However, I overlooked a parent `MenuItem` that may affect my code. I've updated my XAML and apologize for missing that the first time.

Answer (score 3):

The `DataContext` is getting inherited from the `<ContextMenu>`, so you don't need to write anything special in the binding there.

```
<Button Name="Button_1" >
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
            <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding AskBeforeDownloading_Checked}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

To explain in more detail, the `DataContext` binding in the `<ContextMenu>` is saying :

- "RelativeSource Self" means "This item", which is `<ContextMenu>`
- "PlacementTarget" means "The item this item is placed on", which in this case is the `<Button>` object

So you're saying bind the `ContextMenu.DataContext` property to the `Button.DataContext` property.

That property should be your `MainWindowViewModel`, so you can just use a normal binding to bind to the `.AskBeforeDownloading_Checked` property on the DataContext.

Alternatively, you could remove the `.DataContext` binding from the `<ContextMenu>`, and just keep your `<MenuItem>` binding similar to how you have it, but you need to reference the `Button.DataContext.AskBeforeDownloading_Checked`, rather than the `Button.AskBeforeDownloading_Checked` that you have now.

```
<Button Name="Button_1" >
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu>
            <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.AskBeforeDownloading_Checked}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Of the two methods, I prefer the first one as it allows for less code if you are binding more items/properties to the `Button.DataContext` properties.

Comment: Shouldn't my `MenuItem` be checked after doing this? Because it's not, which leads me to believe there is still something else going on here.

Comment: @Ericafterdark `MenuItem.IsChecked` should match whatever `Button.DataContext.AskBeforeDownloading_Checked` is. If it's not staying in sync, then I would double-check that `Button.DataContext` is equal to your `MainWindowViewModel`. I often recommend a 3rd party tool like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) if you're having trouble debugging data bindings

Comment: I prefer your first example as well and I agree that Snoop would be useful for this issue. However, I think it might be important to note that I don't set a `DataContext` for my `Button` in the XAML. Is this okay, or would that be the problem? In addition, would it also be a problem if my `MenuItem` was a child of another `MenuItem`?

Comment: Checkout Updated 2 in my post. It looks like I overlooked something that might be affecting my program.

Comment: @Ericafterdark Yes, the `DataContext` property gets inherited by child controls if it is not specifically set, so you don't need to explicitly set `Button.DataContext` if it's already set to `MainWindowViewModel` further up in the hierarchy. Also, the existence of a second `<MenuItem>` in the tree should not affect either code example posted here :)

Comment: In that case, it's strange that this doesn't seem to be working. What else can I look for?

Comment: @Ericafterdark Are you able to see the MenuItem.DataContext in Snoop, and verify that the `AskBeforeDownloading_Checked` is set to `true`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74365/discussion-between-eric-after-dark-and-rachel).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add PlacementTarget.DataContext. Refer below code.

```
<Button Name="Button_1" >
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu">
                <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.AskBeforeDownloading_Checked}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
```